# Double Ended Queue

Tags: java, deque

The goal is to develop a java program to implement a Dqueue in an efficient manner for all the 6 methods below.   I have to Extend java.util.LinkedList  to Dqueue and implement all of the methods below.

public void  enqueHead(E element),

public void  enqueTail(E element)

public E dequeHead()

public E dequeTail()

public E peekHead() that returns the element at the Head but not remove it.

public E peekTail() that returns the element at the Tail but not remove it.

I have come up with the following code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Dqueue<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
     public void enqueHead(E element) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            add(element);
            return;
         }
        add(0, element);
     }
     public void enqueTail(E element) {
          add(element);
     }
     public E dequeHead() {
         if (isEmpty()) {
           return null;
         }
         return remove(0);
     }
     public E dequeTail() {
         if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
         }
         return remove(size() - 1);
      }
      public E peekHead() {
         if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
       }
         return get(0);
       }
      public E peekTail() {
         if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
       }
         return get(size() - 1);
      }
  }
```

I know that A double ended queue is much like a queue except that the operations of enqueing (adding)  and dequeing (removing) can be done at both ends of the queue.  In a conventional queue, the enque operation is done at the tail and deque is done at the tail but in a Dqueue these operations are allowed at both ends. My only question is if I am doing this correctly? Because it feels a little too simple for it to be right.

Comment: Something wrong with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html?

Comment: Have you noticed that LinkedList is **already** a Deque implementation. The names of the methods in Deque just don't match with the ones you want. Extending LinkedList just to add method aliases seems like a bad idea to me. Just stick with the standard method names.

Comment: It's part of the assignment though!

Comment: This assignment is stupid. But you just need `public E peekTail() { return peekLast(); }`, and add similar aliases for all the other methods.